# How do I resolve an "invalid quantifier" error with regexp in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to transfer the following URL validation function from my PHP code to my javascript code:

```
   this.validate_url = function(field)
    {
        var pattern = new RegExp("^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?([\w]+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?((/?\w+/)+|/?)(\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?");
        var val = $("#" + field).val();

        return pattern.test(val);
    }
```

And this gives me the error:

```
invalid quantifier ?w+=w+)?(&w+=w+)*)?
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since backslash is an escaping character in JavaScript, you'll have to escape *that* to write it in a string:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^((ht|f)tp(s?)\\:\\/\\/|~/|/)?([\\w]+:\\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\\w\\-]+\\.)+([\\w]{2,5}))(:[\\d]{1,5})?((/?\\w+/)+|/?)(\\w+\\.[\\w]{3,4})?((\\?\\w+=\\w+)?(&\\w+=\\w+)*)?");
```

Answer (score 4):

You either need to escape the backslashes within the string declaration:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^((ht|f)tp(s?)://|~/|/)?(\\w+:\\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\\w-]+\\.)+(\\w{2,5}))(:\\d{1,5})?((/?\\w+/)+|/?)(\\w+\\.\\w{3,4})?((\\?\\w+=\\w+)?(&\\w+=\\w+)*)?");
```

Or you use the [regular expression literal syntax **`/`**`expr`**`/`**`flags`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
var pattern = /^((ht|f)tp(s?):\/\/|~\/|\/)?(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w-]+\.)+(\w{2,5}))(:\d{1,5})?((\/?\w+\/)+|\/?)(\w+\.\w{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?/;
```

You should also try to use [non-capturing groups **`(?:`**`expr`**`)`**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) where you don’t need to reference the match of that groups.

Comment: +1 for use of the literal syntax. It avoids (some) of the pain of escaping