# Invalid quatifier. jQuery.validation.js

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-validate

After a quick research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817011/how-do-i-resolve-an-invalid-quantifier-error-with-regexp-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713290/javascript-invalid-quantifier-in-regex), the solutions didn't work for my project.

Here is the regex:

```
"^([A-Za-z0-9\._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}+[;]?)(?:[;][A-Za-z0-9\._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}+[;]?)*$|^$"
```

And here is an error that firebug fires at me whenever I reach email validation step (see regex above):

```
invalid quantifier
hasformat()jquery...tion.js (line 211)
pattern = "\^([A-Za-z0-9\._%-]+@[A...-Za-z]{2,4}+[;]?)*$|^$\"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the `+` after the two sets of `{2,4}`

removed like below gets it running but may not be what you need for the pattern

`^([A-Za-z0-9\._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}[;]?)(?:[;][A-Za-z0-9\._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}[;]?)*$|^$`

Comment: Alternatively, wrap that set in a set of parenthesis, then apply the + quantifier.